# Dividing file by first column of the file PYTHON

Tags: python, file

I have following type of file.txt

```
65000 data1 data2 data3
65000 data1 data2 data3
.
.
.
65000 data1 data2 data3
65001 data1 data2 data3
.
.
.
65001 data1 data2 data3
```

Number of lines with first column (the first number the same) is different for every parameter, so i cannot use simple parameter n=25 for example.

```
enter code here`lines_per_file = 69
 shortfile = None
 with open('longfile.txt') as longfile:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(longfile):
        if lineno % lines_per_file == 0:
            if shortfile:
                shortfile.close()
                short_filename = 'small_file_{}.txt'.format(lineno + lines_per_file)
            shortfile = open(short_filename, "w")
        shortfile.write(line)
    if shortfile:
        shortfile.close()
```

How can I divide file this file on many smaller files

Comment: You can create chunks of file and write those in separate file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

```
lines = 0
shortfile = None
with open('longfile.txt') as longfile:
   for lineno, line in enumerate(longfile):
       new_lines = line.split(' ')[0]
       if lines != new_lines:
           lines = new_lines
           if shortfile:
               shortfile.close()
               short_filename = 'small_file_{}.txt'.format(lines)
           shortfile = open(short_filename, "w")
       shortfile.write(line)
   if shortfile:
       shortfile.close()
```

This should cause a new line file to get created whenever a new number appears at the front

Comment: I guess you aren't addressing the various other problems with the OP's code, but you've introduced an error of your own: `new_num` should be `new_lines` (or vice versa).

Comment: @PM 2Ring  Thanks for the typo and no I figured/hoped this would get him on the right path as his question was pretty vague

Comment: THX very good code thx :)

Comment: @user4252332:  user2097159 has answered your question, and fixed the name creation of `short_filename` but there are still various other problems with the code, in particular, the now-useless `enumerate`. Also, `lines = 0` at the top of the code would probably be better as `lines = None`. Actually, the code would be easier to understand with some more meaningful variable names instead of `lines` and `new_lines`, eg `old_num` and `new_num`.